# makemigrations permisseion denied

Tags: django, makemigrations

i guess i'm stuck at a big problem.
i had to delete the migrations directory in my django app and i thought when i run `python manage.py makemigrations` the directory will be created back, however i got an error

> django.db.migrations.graph.NodeNotFoundError: Migration shoppingcart.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'student', u'0001_initial')

what i did after is recreate the migrations directory and put inside all the migrations files and run `makemigrations` but i'm having another error

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/student/migrations/0007_auto_20170427_1816.py'

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this permission denied issue a few different times. These steps have helped me in the past:

- Make sure you have a blank `__init__.py` file in your migrations directory
- Make sure you you grant correct permissions on the directory, something like `sudo chown <dir_name>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i missed the `__init__.py` file in the directory. the makemigrations is working perfectly now, however when i try to acces the Users in the django admin panel i get this error **(1054, "Unknown column 'student_myuser.myuser_id' in 'field list'")**

Comment: Sounds like the migrations haven't been applied. Try running `python manage.py  migrate` and check the admin panel again.